# Input data to chartJs object

Tags: javascript, charts

Im using chartJs library to create a simple line chart. Problem is that when i have the data in a array and trying to insert it nothing is showing, no error given. if i type in the data it shows correctly.

Manually enter data works but not when in a array.

```
strProdChart1 = '"2019-09-16","2019-09-17"|5,4';
arrProdChart1 = strProdChart1.split("|");
console.log(arrProdChart1[1]);
var objProdChart1 = document.getElementById('ProdChart1');
ProdChart1 =  new Chart( objProdChart1, {
  type: "line",
  data: {"labels": [arrProdChart1[0]],"datasets": [{"label": "test", "data": arrProdChart1[1] ,"borderWidth": 1,"backgroundColor": "red"}]},
  options: {
        color: 'red',
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

the array containes labels and the amounts, getting labels works "arrProdChart1[0]" but when i want to insert the numbers with "arrProdChart1[1]" nothing is showing in the chart. Cant see what i do wrong, if instead replace arrProdChart1[1] with the acctual numbers "5,4" it works fine.
print to the console shows numbers "5,4"
thanks

Comment: i think the data is expecting an array but ur arrProdChart1[1] is not an array 
can u pass a dummy array like [5,4] and see if its work or an object with key value

Comment: You sir, are a genius! changed to this: arrProdChart1[1].split(",") and it worked ASAP :)
Thanks.. 
Not knowing SO to good yet, how can i flag this as correct answer when it's only a comment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data is expecting an array but ur arrProdChart1[1] is not an array 
so convert ur arrProdChart1[1] variable to an array

```
strProdChart1 = '"2019-09-16","2019-09-17"|5,4';
arrProdChart1 = strProdChart1.split("|");
console.log(arrProdChart1[1]);
var newAR = arrProdChart1[1].split(",")
var objProdChart1 = document.getElementById('ProdChart1');
ProdChart1 =  new Chart( objProdChart1, {
  type: "line",
  data: {"labels": [arrProdChart1[0]],"datasets": [{"label": "test", "data": newAR ,"borderWidth": 1,"backgroundColor": "red"}]},
  options: {
        color: 'red',
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

Hope Fully It help